# Multiplying long values?

Tags: java, type-conversion

```
class Main {  
   public static void main (String[] args){  
     long value = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 80;  
     System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);  
     System.out.println(value);  
  }  
}
```

Output is:

```
9223372036854775807
0
```

It's correct if `long value = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 80L;`!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In Java, all math is done in the largest data type required to handle all of the current values.  So, if you have int * int, it will always do the math as an integer, but int * long is done as a long.

In this case, the 1024*1024*1024*80 is done as an Int, which overflows int.

The "L" of course forces one of the operands to be an Int-64 (long), therefore all the math is done storing the values as a Long, thus no overflow occurs.

Comment: Arithmetic on, say, `short`s isn't done as `short`s, it's done as `int`s.

Comment: Tom- That is very interesting, I'd never known that.  I just tested it with two shorts (in C#, but similar action), and it DID do the math as an Integer...

It must be just using an Int as the default value for plain numeric types.

Comment: i.e.
short x = 0;
short y = 0;

x = x + y;

would give a type mismatch error.

Comment: Prateek-  It doesn't though, the compiler is smart enough to make the differentiation.

Comment: Prattek: There's a bit of target typing going on there. You can also do `myShort += anotherShort;` but not `myShort = myShort + anotherShort;`. I like aribtrary precision integers...

Comment: Erich: Integer arithmetic without `long` is done as `int`. Floating point arithmetic without `double` is done as `float` (I think I forget what happens you do `long+float`). I still like arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Comment: That actually sounds familiar, and is a pretty reliable rule, it makes sense that would be the way it happens.
long+float is done as a double I think, which is why you can do 5/3.0 and have it work.

Comment: your explanation is invalid. If your number is long you need to add L at the end of a number of size long. Valid -> 31536000000L*2 . Invalid -> 31536000000*2; [as L not added].

Comment: Moreover, 1000*60*60*24*365L this gives a different result then 1000*60*60*24*365*1L. 
As multiplication starts from L to R, 1000*60*60*24 -> gives integer number, and when you multiply it with 365L  it give long as result. But when you multiply it with 365 -> output is greater than 32 bits [36 bits] and compiler removes all extra 4 bits and makes it 32 bits again and then multiplies it with 1L resulting in invalid result.

Comment: Some reference would be handy. For example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html (but I do not get which part does happen in this case)

Answer (score 6):

The integer literals are `int`s. The `int`s overflow. Use the `L` suffix.

```
long value = 1024L * 1024L * 1024L * 80L;
```

If the data came from variables either cast or assign to longs beforehand.

```
long value = (long)a * (long)b;

long aL = a;
long bL = b;
long value = aL*bL
```

Strictly speaking you can get away with less suffices, but it's probably better to be clear.

Also not the lowercase `l` as a suffix can be confused as a `1`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's because by default java treats literals as integers, not longs. So, without the L on 80 the multiplication overflows.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
long value = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 80;
```

multiplies some integers together, converts it to a long and then assigns the result to a variable. The actual multiplication will be done by javac rather than when it runs.

Since int is 32 bits, the value is wrapped and results in a zero.

As you say, using long values in the right hand side will give a result which only wraps if it exceeds 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, per your requirement, you wanted to multiply these values `1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 80;`

In calculator I see values coming 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 80=85899345920.

Here you go your java code: These are monetary value calculation in java

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal("1024");
        BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal("1024");
        BigDecimal bd3 = new BigDecimal("1024");
        BigDecimal bd4 = new BigDecimal("80");
        BigDecimal bd5 = bd1.multiply(bd2).multiply(bd3).multiply(bd4);
        System.out.println(bd5); // output comes: 85899345920
    }
}
```