# Really confused by java data type in this specific case

Tags: java, long-integer

```
public class Test {
        public static void main(String [] s) {
            int x = 99999;
            long y = 99999;

            long res = x * x;
            System.out.println("x^2 = " + res);
            res = y * y;
            System.out.println("y^2 = " + res);
        }
    }



 Output: 
    x^2 = 1409865409
    y^2 = 9999800001
```

I am really confused to see the output from the above code segment. I expected to get the same (correct) answer but here x^2 is actually wrong!

Comment: you  are running into an overflow. Once `x` reached the value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` adding `+1` to `x` will result in `x` beeing `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494862/multiplying-long-values

Comment: In first case you multiplied two ints and then casted to long, in second you multiplied two longs

Answer (score 8):

`99999 * 99999` = `1001010100000010001101011011000001` in binary (if you count these you will find out that you need 34 bits to represent this number in memory).

**int** is **32-bit** long so two **MSB**s are cut out.

That gives you `01010100000010001101011011000001b` = `1409865409` decimal as a result.

Assigning this value to 64-bit long doesn't change the result, multiplication of two integers gives you integer as a result.

Answer (score 3):

That is because you multiply `integers` `x * x` and the result of that will be `integer` (temporary variable, we talk here about the result of `x * x` operation, not `res =` part). Since the result will be bigger then `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, you will get some "strange" number. Then you place that number in the variable of `long` type.

This is how you fix this problem:

```
long res = 1l * x * x;
```

Now, it will calculate `1l * x`, and since first number is `long`, it will calculate this as `long`, then multiply with `x`, and again, since first number is `long`, the result will be `long`, then this result will be placed in the variable `res`.

In similar way you fix problem with losing decimals, like for:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 3;
double d = a / b;
```

Result for this will be `3.0`. But, if you do this:

```
double d = (1d *a) / b;
d = a / (b * 1d);
d = (double) a / d;
```

Both will be `3.3333333333333335` (this `5`, well thats another problem...).
Also, casting to double for one of the variables works too (thanks @Aconcagua).

Comment: Why multiplying with a constant - you simply can cast the first (or second...) operand to long or double respectively.

Comment: that works to... dunno, got used to doing this, for no reason...

Comment: You are introducing a surplus operation (multiplication) this way. It should get optimized away, though, but you rely on optimization then while you had an alternative without having to rely on anything further...

Comment: Not sure, if common sense, but furthermore, I personally consider casting as expressing the intention more explicitly/clearly.

Comment: Well, what I do is I place 1d into static variable, so it gets more readable. But, yes, there is a cost of additional variable, but I guess casting and multiplication with 1 should be equally fast, by theory. Biggest question here is, what will JIT do in both case.

Comment: If a constant, the variable should not consume any memory... Both variants are equally fast, *if* the multiplication is optimized away, otherwise you get an additionally operation (on the FPU in case of double). The former, however, is what I would expect from any halfway feasible JIT, so in effect, you should be right...

Answer (score 3):

Because first `x * x` is done in `int` space and only then the result is put into a `long`. Therefore even though the `long` variable is large enough to hold the result, before putting the result into `long` it is first calculated as an `int` product and the result is truncated because it doesn't fit in `int`