# Printing large multiplied numbers in java

Tags: java, int, multiplication, primitive-types, system.out

I'm doing an AP Comp Sci Review sheet and I do not understand why when I compile

`System.out.println(365 * 24 * 3600 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);` the answer is 0. I understand that an int is 32 bits and has a maximum of 2147483647 and could not give you 3386152216166400 but why wouldn't it give an overflow exception error or a similar error?

Comment: Please see [Why, In Java arithmetic, overflow or underflow will never throw an Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085286/why-in-java-arithmetic-overflow-or-underflow-will-never-throw-an-exception)

Comment: Sorry for duplicating, I thought it was a unique question, I'm still quite a beginner at Java. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2),

> The integer operators do not indicate overflow or underflow in any
>   way.

That's why you are not getting any exception.

The results are [specified by the language](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.1) as follows,

> If an integer multiplication overflows, then the result is the
>   low-order bits of the mathematical product as represented in some
>   sufficiently large two's-complement format. As a result, if overflow
>   occurs, then the sign of the result may not be the same as the sign of
>   the mathematical product of the two operand values.

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE

Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1 == Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

That's why you are getting zero as the result.

Comment: Isn't `Integer.MIN_VALUE equal to -2147483648? So why doesn't it return that?

Comment: Yes, It is. If you try to print `Integer.MIN_VALUE` it will print `-2147483648`. But if you try to print values lower than `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, you will get `Integer.MAX_VALUE` rather than correct value since Integers can't represent such values.

Comment: I understand how under min_value makes Max value (2147483648) and how over max_value gives you min_value (-2147483648).  But then, where does the number 0 come into play?

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `L` to identify that one of the values is of primitive type [`long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

```
System.out.println(365L * 24 * 3600 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
/*                    ^
 * 'L' to indicate that one of the factors is long
 */
```

> In Java, all math is done in the largest data type required to handle
>   all of the current values. So, if you have int * int, it will always
>   do the math as an integer, but int * long is done as a long.
>
> In this case, the 1024*1024*1024*80 is done as an Int, which overflows
>   int.
>
> The "L" of course forces one of the operands to be an Int-64 (long),
>   therefore all the math is done storing the values as a Long, thus no
>   overflow occurs.
>
> Credit goes to Erich: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1494884/5645656

**EDIT:**

> In many cases Java is based on C or C++ and these are based on
>   Assembly. An overflow/underflow is silent in C and C++ and almost
>   silent in assembly (unless you check special flags). This is likely
>   due to the fact that C and C++ didn't have exceptions when they were
>   first proposed. If you wanted to see overflows/underflows you just
>   used a larger type. e.g. long long int or long double ;) BTW assembly
>   has something similar to exceptions called traps or interrupts,
>   overflows/underflow doesn't cause a trap AFAIK.
>
> Credit goes to Peter Lawrey: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15998029/5645656

TIP: Sometimes using google can answer your question before you ask it.

Comment: The question is about why Java decided not to raise an exception here, not why there is overflow.  Also, your solution wouldn't work to avoid overflow here, because `int` multiplication, going from left to right, would overflow before you get to the `long`.

Comment: @rgettman I misinterpreted the question. Thanks  for saving me ;)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use BigInteger.

```
BigInteger bi1, bi2, bi3;  

      // assign values to bi1, bi2
      bi1 = new BigInteger("123");
      bi2 = new BigInteger("50");

      // perform multiply operation on bi1 using bi2
      bi3 = bi1.multiply(bi2);

      String str = "Result of multiply is " +bi3;;

      // print bi3 value
      System.out.println( str );
```