# Java multiple numbers in one line

Tags: java, type-conversion, integer, long-integer

Please consider below code on java:

```
        long maxDays = 1000;
        maxDays = maxDays * 24;
        maxDays = maxDays * 60;
        maxDays = maxDays * 60;
        maxDays = maxDays * 377;
        System.out.println(maxDays);  // The result is 32572800000
```

Now I try to do it in one line:

```
        maxDays = 1000 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 377;
        System.out.println(maxDays);  // The result is -1786938368
```

Why the result changed !

I think it must be about type conversion from `int` to `long`, but I don't know why?

AND how can I do it in one line in correct way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiplying long values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494862/multiplying-long-values)

Comment: in the first example at the right of the equation sign you have one long `maxDays`, but in the second, after the equation sign you have 5 int values that will cause  `Numeric overflow` exception. you have to define one of the 5 integers as long, lilke: 1000L*24*60*60*377;

Answer (score 2):

You're right: all the numbers (1000, 24, ...) are seen as `int` and producing an overflow during the calculation. Only the result will be implicitely type casted to `long`.

To handle the calculation, you can mark all these values as `long` by adding a `L` at the end of the number like this:

```
long maxDays = 1000L * 24L * 60L * 60L * 377L;
```

Also it would be enough to declare only one number as `long` like this:

```
long maxDays = 1000L * 24 * 60 * 60 * 377;
```